# Getting an error message when I try to take values from an array to insert into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I am getting an error this error:

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array
```

Here's the relevant code - I am trying to to take all of the values from an array ($culture), and insert each into a MySQL query individually.

```
if (isset($_POST["orgid"])  && ($_POST['orgid'] !== '')) {
$orgid = $_POST['orgid'];
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE organization SET org_name='".$orgname."', add_1='".$add1."', add_2='".$add2."', city='".$city."', state='".$state."', zip='".$zip."', url='".$url."', email='".$email."', phone='".$phone."', contact='".$contact."', hours='".$hours."', notes='".$notes."', description='".$description."' WHERE org_id='".$orgid."'");   

while ($cultrow = mysql_fetch_array($culture)) {
    $query = mysql_query("update org_cult_xref set org_id='".$orgid."', cult_id='".$cultrow."'");    
}
}
```

Here's the form info:

```
<select name="culture[]" multiple="multiple"><?php
    while ($cultrow = mysql_fetch_array($rescult)) {
        ECHO '<option name="culture[]" value="'. stripslashes($cultrow['cult_id']) .'">'. stripslashes($cultrow['cult_desc']) .'</option>';
    }
    ?>
        </select></fieldset>
```

Comment: where did you set `$culture`?

Comment: $culture is set from all the variables of a picklist. Let me show you.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() is used for retrieving data from a query and not for populating an update statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $culture is not some sort of resource returned from a mysql_query function, you should supply the $query to mysql_fetch_array function. Of course if you want to use the result from the first update query.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) structure?

```
foreach($culture as $cultid) {
    $query = mysql_query("update org_cult_xref set org_id='".$orgid."', cult_id='".$cultid."'");    
}
```

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense - I am so used to getting arrays from MySQL! Sorry, still new to PHP. Also, I like your handle, used a similar one for years.

Comment: Hrm, this does not appear to update org_cult_xref. Neither does an "insert into" - why would this be?